# Router is never used, but Routes do not work without importing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

If I remove `Router` import from `Main.js` (I alrady use router in `index.js` and Router is never used in `Main.js`) - app pages in `Main.js` stop showing app at all. Wrapping `Route`s in another Router does not work either. What should I do?

**index.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";

import Navigation from "./components/Navigation/Navigation.js";
import Main from "./components/Main/Main.js";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navigation />
      <Main />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Main.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "../../pages/Home.js";
import Contacts from "../../pages/Contacts.js";
import About from "../../pages/About.js";
import CardList from "../../components/CardList/CardList.js";

const Main = () => (
  <>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
      <Redirect to="/products" />
    </Route>
    <Route path={["/products/:id", "/products"]} component={CardList} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
    <Route path="/contact" component={Contacts}></Route>
  </>
);

export default Main;
```

Comment: Remove the redundant import, restart your devserver and hard refresh the browser, it looks like a weird problem that might be just some internals bugging out.

Comment: @JohnSmith done all of this, still does not work. No errors and app works, just pages do not show up in `Main`.

Comment: @John check in the browser dev tools maybe element are in the DOM you just cant see

Comment: @Rostyslav checked. It is not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first routes should come between switch

```
const Main = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}>
        <Redirect to="/products" />
      </Route>
      <Route path={["/products/:id", "/products"]} component={CardList} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contacts}></Route>
  <Switch/>
  </>
);
```

Comment: did it, now pages show up, but do not switch untill browser page refresh. Tried both with and without `<></>`

Comment: UPD: I imported `Switch, Route, Redirect` not as `BrowserRouter` and it works now. Why is that?

Comment: the browser router  uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.
and switch Renders the first child <Route> or <Redirect> that matches the location.
I recommend to you to look for react-router-6 they gonna bring new changes and change stuff a little bit to make it easyer